CAPTCHA dialog box is overflowing
CAPTCHA dialog box is overflowing. Example:

Tested with the latest version of Chrome on Windows 10.

What’s the creepy ... thing with a red glowing dot under a glassy cover in the middle? If this is genuinely a part of the interface, I’d say this is more serious problem than a little bit of text overflow.

@EmilJeřábek Hal 9000. Agreed, esp. on mobile.

@Emil It's a pop culture movie reference
